# Unable to Run 'Hello World' Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy

I am attempting to run a basic hello world app for a Python GUI library called kivy--which the developers provide [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#quickstart)--in the new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows environment. I've saved the example code as `main.py` as shown below:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # my current kivy version

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When I attempt to run this simple app using `python main.py` (or even `sudo python main.py` if something was needing permissions) I get the following error:

```
[INFO   ][Logger      ] Record log in /home/jdaymude/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-08-17_3.txt
[INFO   ][Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ][Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 709, in <module>
     Clock = register_context('Clock', ClockBase)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/context.py", line 83, in register_context
     instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 436, in __init__
     self._start_tick = self._last_tick = self.time()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 273, in _time
     raise OSError(_errno, strerror(_ernno))
 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I haven't found any other StackOverflow questions with a similar error, and going through the [kivy issue tracker](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) didn't indicate any related issues with the software. To me, this indicates that I'm doing something wrong, so any suggestions would be most helpful. My Ubuntu version is 14.04, I've updated `python`, `python3`, `kivy`, and all of their dependencies, and have installed/successfully tested an Xterm program to launch the GUI when the kivy app does work.

After some discussion in the comments, I'm including details on installation for further clarification. I followed the instructions the kivy developers provided for [Installation on Linux](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu-saucy-and-above), which boils down to the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-kivy python3-kivy
```

Since I'm new to kivy and wanted to cover all my bases, I also installed a handful of what the install guide calls ["common dependencies"](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#common-dependencies) using `sudo apt-get install`, including: `python-dev`, `python3-dev`, `python-pip`, and all the others shown at the linked page for `SDL2` and `pygame`. Although not relevant to my efforts since I wanted a global install, I also followed their instructions for using `virtualenv` and that also gave the same error.

Comment: Does the log say anything. And I suppose you allready checked that you dont have a my.kv file in your directory.

Comment: Hi @EL3PHANTEN, the log's contents are the same as the output shown above, just formatted differently. However, I know I do not have a `my.kv` file in the directory with `main.py`... but as a beginner also don't know why I would need one to run a simple app. Are you saying I should have one? Or that having one causes problems?

Comment: No just making sure you dont have it. If you had a file called my.kv, it would be automatically loaded, since your app is named MyApp.

Comment: Ah, I remember seeing that in one of their crash course videos; thanks for the reminder! Still doesn't solve this issue though... do you have any other ideas I can try?

Comment: No I dont know. Your code works. And it should work with ubuntu. So I guess there is something wrong with the installation. How did you install?

Comment: I updated the question to describe the install process.

Comment: I can't help but notice that your python version isn't the latest version of 2.7. Not sure if that matters

Comment: @cricket_007, interesting catch! I ran `sudo apt-get install --upgrade python` and it reports being the most recent version, despite being 2.7.6 instead of 2.7.10. Could be an issue with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: Oh, you are using Bash on Windows. That doesn't have a DISPLAY variable, so I'm not sure running a GUI app is even possible. Why can't you run Kivy directly from Windows?

Comment: It technically doesn't, but I've successfully exported a display variable and gotten Firefox to show up in Bash on Windows after installing an Xterm program. Technically unsupported behavior but possible. You're right in that I could run Kivy directly, I was just trying out the new Bash as Linux is something I'm more comfortable developing on. Might be my only choice at this point though, short of standing up a VM.

Comment: Or make a live usb of ubuntu :D or install ubuntu aside of windows

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a solution was already posted somewhere. A quick Google search didn't show up anything. A hack I found was patching `lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py` file (in your virtualenv). In `def _get_sleep_obj():` function definition, force the code to go to `if True or platform in ('win32', 'cygwin'):` path.

With this change, the "Hello Word" and other example apps started working.